# Is sqlite3 backend for SOCI Database Access Library production ready?

Tags: c++, database, sqlite

SQLITE3 backend for SOCI Database Access Library is said to bo not officially supported. (Not included in distribution archive for version 3.0, only in source code repository).

Does anybody use it in production application?

Or maybe know any serious applications, that use it?

It seems like library is quite popular, but i need a proof of it's "production ready" status to be able to use in my production application.

Answer (score 2):

I have used it with sqlite, and it was fine. I did not encounter bugs, and looking through my local Perforce soci repository, I only see compiler portability changes, not bug fixes. The application has been in production since mid-2009 and I have not received any bug reports.

Soci 3 is from 2008; that fact that sqlite3 support isn't in the "release" might not mean much.